# Why some rows disappear when adding new rows in specific place?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a problem which I can not solve.. When I add new rows in a specific place in a datafreme, the rows after new rows disappear(it is like whe new rows step on the old ones and hide/remove them).. I take dataframe from excel file, also I use pandas.

```
if (first_table.iloc[first_table_row_number, 1:32].sum().all() == True):  
    my_row = first_table.iloc[first_table_row_num, 0:32]
    final_table.iloc[final_table_row_num + 91] = my_row
    final_table.loc[(96+a):(96+a)] = [2023, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    final_table.loc[(97+a):(97+a)] = ['I', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    final_table.loc[(98+a):(98+a)] = ['II', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    final_table.loc[(99+a):(99+a)] = ['III', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    final_table.loc[(100+a):(100+a)] = ['IV', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

first_table - table from where i take values
final_table - table in which I want put values from first_table
final_table_row_num - it is index row from which I count where other rows should be
first_table_row_number - indexed row from which I take values to final_table.

As you can see I only need to add 2023 in a first column, then new row 'I' in a first column and so on. Other columns should stay empty, I will add some values from first_table.

So I want to add 5 new rows to final_table, but when I do that these 5 new rows delete existing rows...
Is there any solution to this? Do I need to do something with row index?

Comment: Perhaps better to use `pandas.DataFrame.append` and then sort rows as you wish?

Comment: @johnjohn `append` is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You could slice and use concat to get what you want.

Example:

```
line = pd.DataFrame([2023, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
df2 = concat([df.iloc[:96], line, df.iloc[96:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add lines for example between line 1 and 2, then add to the index between them both - 1.5.
df.loc[1.5] = ....